# Crontab inexplicably restored to default

Tags: cron

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 model B running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)`. It has been running flawlessly for months and does a bunch of cronjobs. A few run every minute. Some run Once or twice a day. Just yesterday I noticed some cronjobs did not seem to execute, examing the crontab with `crontab -e` (the way I always edit crontab) I discovered  only the heading comments of the void crontab as it comes on a new instal. All my cronjobs where gone. This is the only clue I could find, in /var/log/syslog

```
crontab[6088]: (root) DELETE (root)
```

I have no experince with this and I am stumped.

My questions:
What are the reasons this could happen and what can be done to prevent it in the future?